# How would someone create a machine learning algorithm that extracts the speaker from a book/novel?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, text-analysis

Basically organizes the content based on the speaker?

Excerpt From: Robert Louis Stevenson. “The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde.”

Example Input:

> But Lanyon's face changed, and he held up a trembling hand. "I wish to see or hear no more of Dr. Jekyll," he said in a loud, unsteady voice. "I am quite done with that person; and I beg that you will spare me any allusion to one whom I regard as dead.

Example Output:

```
[

“Narrator”: “But Lanyon's face changed, and he held up a trembling hand.”,

“Lanyon”: “I wish to see or hear no more of Dr. Jekyll”,

“Narrator”: “he said in a loud, unsteady voice.”,

“Lanyon”: “I am quite done with that person; and I beg that you will spare me any allusion to one whom I regard as dead.”

]
```

Comment: Please give a more specific example of input and output.

Comment: In general, this is an unsolved problem, because it requires deep understanding of all existing roles and their interaction.

Comment: @DavidDale Hey david I added an example to my original question with input and output

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard of the algorithm that does exactly this. But there are two well known problem that could be useful: **named entity recognition** (to find all potential speakers) and **anaphora resolution** (to decide who "he" or "she" is in each case).

You would also need to train a classifier that for each quoted chunk of text to decide whether it is a direct speech. And you would probably need another classifier to decide for each identified piece of speech and for each identified speaker in the context, how likely is that this speech actually belongs to this speaker.